# Ranking the user with points in users table

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id   |   point
1         500
2        5252
5        4848
8        322
10       5959
```

I have table like this, I want to see the ranking of the user with the id = 5 according to points.

How do I do this with Mysql query?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb264565(v=sql.90).aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) + 1 AS rank
  FROM tbl
 WHERE point > (SELECT point
                  FROM tbl
                 WHERE id = 5)
```

Comment: Nice solution. Only thing I'd suggest is an `AS` on the selected value to make the purpose more clear.